# Saving by month to include week number

Tags: vba, excel, save, monthcalendar

I am looking to save data from one file to another based on Month, but if a week falls in to another month part way through, I still would like to save the data with the current week. Here's the codes as it stands which works fine for saving by month:

```
'Copy Data to Workbook Weekly Monthly

Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

FileMonth = Month(Date)
StrFileMonth = Format(Date, "MMM")

Filepath = "F:\Customer Services\UK Order File\Monthly Figures\" & StrFileMonth & "\" & "UK_Orders_Monthly.xlsm"

Workbooks.Open (Filepath), _
UpdateLinks:=True

Worksheets("Data").Activate
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Looks like you need to perform some grade school maths using Day(Date) and WeekDay(Date).

Comment: Agreed, I've created a table to look up against to provide the correct month to save against, but its how to reference that in the file path to save it

Comment: If you have a table set up to specify the correct month, just use that value instead of `strFileMonth`.  Otherwise, do as @Jeeped suggested, subtract `Weekday(Date)-1` (or whatever suits your week scheme) from `Date` and format the result as `"MMM"`.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K abd Jeeped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **True** in VBA is considered **-1** when used mathematically (contrary to a worksheet's TRUE which is +1).

If the weekday(Date) is greater then the day(Date) then the month should be last month; e.g. dateadd("m", -1, Date). If it is equal to or less than the day of the month then the month is the current month; e.g. dateadd("m", 0, Date).

```
StrFileMonth = Format(dateadd("m", weekday(date, vbmonday) > day(date), date), "mmm")
```

I've used vbMonday where Monday = 1; the WeekDay VBA function defaults to Sunday = 1.